# How are words in native English part of the vocabulary typically so short to forestall morphemic spelling?

Tags: historical-linguistics

[*Why Do Languages Change?* (2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521546931) by [R. L. Trask (1944-2004)](https://www.librarything.com/author/traskrl). pp. 138, 139.

> This habit of retaining French spellings in English contributed to another
>   prominent feature of modern English spelling. This feature is called *morphemic
>   spelling*, and the label means that an element is spelled in essentially the same way even when its pronunciation changes greatly as a result of the addition of suffixes. For example, we took from Norman French such pairs as *nature* and
>   *natural*, *medicine* and *medicinal*, *physic* (an archaic word for ‘medicine’) and *physician*, *oblige* and *obligation*, and our decisions about how to spell these pairs have made morphemic spelling the norm in the elevated and technical part of English vocabulary. **Compare the quite different policy followed in the native English part of the vocabulary, where the words are typically so short that morphemic spelling would be hard to maintain: *deep/depth*; *gold/gild*; *bake/batch*; *long/length*; and so on.**

I can pronounce *deepth, *length effortlessly?  Thus how does the shortness of the words hinder morphemic spelling of these words from Old English? I can pronounce *deepth, *longth effortlessly?

I agree though that *bake* + *tch* is cumbersome to pronounce. *baketch would shift to <batch>, as [a] would be palatized.

Comment: Yes another account? I honestly don’t understand why.

Comment: What does being able to pronounce *deepth and not being able to pronounce *baketch have to do with morphemic spelling? Morphemic spelling is about spelling. It has nothing to do with why we pronounce "obligation" the way we do, but with why we spell it with "oblig-" despite not pronouncing it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what Trask meant in this passage, so I can't explain it to you.

I would actually disagree with the statement that English follows "quite different" strategies of spelling in French/Latin vocabulary and native English vocabulary, with morphemic spelling being "the norm" in the former and typically absent in the latter.

In fact, even learned vocabulary has a number of non-morphemic elements:

- one of the most pervasive is "silent e" deletion (we write *natural, medicinal, obligation* rather than *natureal, medicineal, obligateion:* unless you argue that *nature, medicine, oblige* are all non-simple forms ending in some morpheme represented by -*e,* it is not morphological to have the *e* in the spelling of the base word but not in the derived word)
- In general, Latin spelling was phonetic/phonemic rather than morphological, and the English spelling (also pronunciation) of many words is based on Latin allomorphy: e.g. the same prefix is spelled four different ways in *immature, innocent, irreverent, illegal.*
  We also see such changes affecting the spelling of roots in suffixed words like *permission* (vs. *permit*),  *compulsion* (vs. *compel*), or *transcription* (vs *transcribe*).
- Sometimes the spelling (and pronunciation) of the more basic word shows more influence from French pronunciation changes than the spelling of the suffixed word: e.g. *destroy/destruction, deceive/deception, pronounce/pronunciation.*
- Some miscellaneous things based on English spelling oddities: e.g. the alternation between *-ke* and *-c-* in words like *revoke, revocation,* or  *-l-* and *-ll-* in words like *repel, repellent,* or *-y* and *-i-* in words like *vary, variation; glory, glorious; territory, territorial.*

I'm taking the "silent e" deletion and "transcribe/transcription" examples from "[English orthography is not “close to optimal”](http://aclweb.org/anthology/N/N15/N15-1056.pdf)", by Garrett Nicolai and Grzegorz Kondrak, 2015 (mentioned in the following Faculty of Language blog post: http://facultyoflanguage.blogspot.com/2016/09/chomsky-was-wrong.html).

Furthermore, native English vocabulary has some elements that could be considered morphemic:

- The suffixes *-ed, -s,* and *-'s* have multiple pronunciations that are not indicated in the spelling (aside from the phonologically conditioned spelling variant *-es* for the /ɨz/ allomorph of *-s,* and the use of *-t* in the spelling of a few irregular verbs such as *slept* and *learnt*).
- *ea* is pronounced differently in the (diachronically, at least) related pairs of words *steal/stealth* and *heal/health,* but the spelling is the same. *Ou* is pronounced differently in *south/southern.*
- *ng* is pronounced differently in *strong, long, young* and *stronger, longer, younger,* but the spelling remains the same (this is maybe a bit questionable since English does't have any regular way of representing the distinction between [ŋg] and [ŋ] in spelling)

It's a bit hard to find examples, but this could partly just be because there isn't a lot of inherited native English morphology where "pronunciation changes greatly as a result of the addition of suffixes" (productive inherited English suffixes such as *-ness* generally don't change the pronunciation of the base). I'm not sure I would agree with the implication that *bake* and *batch* are morphologically related at all from a purely synchronic perspective.

And it's not hard to imagine how English orthography could be made even more morphemic if its spelling were revised for this purpose: a spelling like "deepth" would have a fairly unambiguous meaning, even if it wouldn't accurately indicate the pronunciation /dɛpθ/ of the word that it is supposed to represent. In German, the morphological changes caused by the phonological process of umlaut are represented in writing by adding the ¨ diacritic to a vowel letter: we could do this in English to get something like *man/män, goose/gööse, mouse/möüse, guld/güld, long/löngth.*

Answer (score 1):

"Morphemic spelling" is a quality of English *orthography (spelling)*, not of English *morphology* or *phonology*. It's not about why English pronounces "obligation" differently from "oblige", but about why English *spells* them the same despite *not* pronouncing them.

/ˌɑbləˈɡeɪʃən/ is spelled "obligation", even though that's not what you'd get from the "default" spelling rules (/ʃ/ is spelled "sh", short vowels are followed by two consonants, etc.), because it's built from the morphemes /əˈblaɪdʒ/ and /eɪʃən/, and those morphemes are spelled "oblige" and "-ation".

So:

> I can pronounce *deepth, *length effortlessly?

That's not relevant here. English patterns /diːp/ to /dɛpθ/, so that word, /dɛpθ/, needs to be spelled. The fact that you can just as easily pronounce /diːpθ/ (and that in an alternate history, that might have even ended up as an English word) doesn't matter; it's not a word, so we don't need to spell it.

The question is how English chooses to spell the word /dɛpθ/.

A (roughly) phonetic way to spell it would be to spell the short /ɛ/ as a single "e" rather than a doubled "ee", to get "depth".

A morphemic way to spell it would be to combine the spellings of the two morphemes "deep" and "-th" to get "deepth". Notice that this "deepth" would still be pronounced /dɛpθ/.

---

So, is Trask right that English avoids morphemic spelling in short morphemes, and that's why most derived native words end up spelled phonetically? I don't know. Trask's examples aren't entirely compelling.

"Depth" could easily have been spelled as "deepth", and "length" as "longth"; the fact that they're one syllable and 4-5 letters isn't an obvious problem.

And with "gild", the problem isn't that the root morpheme is too short—it's that there is no suffix to spell. You'd have to invent a silent morpheme that doesn't exist, just to give it a spelling (say, "goldt"),<sup>1</sup> and then make sure that it didn't collide with other morphemes (after all, you can add all kinds of suffixes to "gild", and they all need to be spelled; that's trivial with "gild", but not with "goldt"). Many of the inherited derivational systems are pure vowel alternation, like "gild", but borrowed systems aren't.

And, as [sumelic's answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29799/23611) demonstrates, there are already plenty of examples where we *do* apply morphological spelling to native words, and they work just fine on words even shorter than "depth"—like "ads" instead of "adz".

I suspect it actually has much more to do with the most influential spelling standardizers and reformers thinking in terms of *etymology*, than (consciously or otherwise) deciding between morphological or phonetic spelling. (In fact, it looks like that's exactly what Trask was talking about before this paragraph, since it starts with "This habit of retaining French spellings…") To people who cared enough about spelling to want to force everyone else to do it their way, it was important that we be able to see the Greek, Latin, and French roots in our spelled words. That means using a spelling that closely matches the parent language in all derived forms. Sometimes our derived words pattern the same way as the parent language, so it ends up looking phonetic; sometimes, they pattern differently, so it ends up looking morphemic.<sup>3</sup> The latter happens more often, but that's just because of the contingent fact that an originally-umlauting language was borrowing from a mainly-suffixing language rather than vice-versa.<sup>2</sup> So, we ended up with morphemic spelling for most derivations of most borrowed words.

---

<sub>1. As sumelic points out, we could borrow the German umlaut diacritic, and spell "gild" as "göld", even if that isn't actually how ¨ works in German or any of the other Germanic languages. But I don't think that would be substantially different from inventing a new silent suffix.</sub>

<sub>2. Of course it's possible that if things had been the other way around—say, if England had ended up speaking a French dialect with lots of Old English borrowed into it—that etymological spelling wouldn't have looked as attractive a few centuries later?</sub>

<sub>3. Also notice that, e.g., "-ment" is itself borrowed from French, while "-th" is not just native, but so old it's no longer productive. So, "-th" is much less likely to be applied to borrowed words than "-ment" is, so the idea of needing to preserve the etymology of "depth" is less likely to occur to anyone.</sub>